# getting the position of a floated element

Tags: jquery, position, css-float

I have some code like this:

```
<style>
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: green;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;

}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
</style>


<div id="wrapper">
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
<div class="box">6</div>
</div>
```

I need to get the left,top of each of the boxes relative to #wrapper.  I'm trying to do this through jQuery.position() however, I am not getting the right results.  Keep getting 0,0.  Can anybody else.  I think the problem here is floats... if these were absolutely positioned, I would be reading them correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Here some jQuery code which will alert the left position. This works with floating well.

```
$(function() {
    $('#wrapper div').each( function( index, item ) {
            alert( $(this).position().left);
    });
});
```

here a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ytGYS/

Answer (score 5):

Position actually works fine, just make sure you clearfix your #wrapper so that it has a height and width. The problem you're having is that with all of the elements floated, your parent #wrapper gets collapsed and has no dimensions, so jQuery can't figure out how far one thing is from the other.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle with your mark-up and a code example: http://jsfiddle.net/tBwwr/

Comment: same here. I'm leaving office now, so you have to take over :-)

Comment: haha.  I'm fiddlin' around while I write `PowerShell` all day to backup SQL Server DBs ughh... @.$  cya later :]

Answer (score 0):

+1 for andrewheins answer:

You are totally right; if the #wrapper is too small to display all the floated elements next to each other, the $().offset() will give you the position of the elements one under each other.

The annoying thing is when the $().offset() is checked before the #wrapper gets is correct width. For example if there are two $(document).ready() functions which are executed in the wrong order. (first get offset(), then set width)

Note: I have not enough reputation to vote his answer up or leave a comment.